# Routing problems, PHP MVC

Tags: php, model-view-controller, routes

I'm writing a simple router on php. And i'm faced with problem. For example, i have an array of routes, like this:

```
[
  '/' => [ 'url' => '/', 'method' => 'get', 'action' => 'HomeController@index' ]
  'book/add' => ['url' => 'book/add', 'method' => 'get',  'action' => 'BookController@add']
  'book/:id' => ['url' => 'book/:id', 'method' => 'get', 'action' => 'BookController@view', 'params' => [':id']]

]
```

In my router have this code:

```
if(array_key_exists($searchPath, $routes)) {
 //...
}
```

`$searchPath` - it's my `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`

`$routes` - it's my routes array.

And if in `$searchPath` will be `book/add` or '/' - all will be okay, i'm can find route in my array and do something. But what if in `$searchPath` will be `book/1` - how I can detect route that I need(`book/:id`)? Someone has an idea?

Comment: You could make a regex to parse the `book/<digit>` as `book/:id`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've found the solution. I've used this class: https://github.com/gpolguere/path-to-regexp-php

My routes:

```
'book/:id' => ['url' => 'book/:id', 'method' => 'get', 'action' => 'BookController@view', 'params' => [':id'], 'regexp' => \PathToRegexp::convert('book/:id')]
```

Finding route:

```
 foreach($this->routes as $route)
    {
        if( preg_match($route['regexp'], $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']))
        {
            $currentRoute = $route;
            break;
        }
    }
```